# Django CARDINALITY Query does not allow filtering by equals but does work for < or >

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a Document model, which contains an ArrayField of pages. I want to find a list of all documents that have zero pages.

Model field:

```
content = ArrayField(models.TextField(), default=list, blank=True)
```

I use an annotation function to first create a calculated field for number of pages, and then try to filter on pages equal zero. Here is the query I'm trying to run:

```
qs = Document.objects.all() \
            .annotate(content_len=Func(F('content'), function='CARDINALITY')) \
            .exclude(content_len=0) # this DOESN'T WORK
            .exclude(content_len__lt=1) # this WORKS
```

The version that doesn't work generates the following SQL error:

```
WHERE CARDINALITY("dockets_document"."content") = 0::text[]

>>> psycopg2.errors.CannotCoerce: cannot cast type integer to text[]
```

Comment: What if you use `Func(F('content'), function='CARDINALITY', output_field=IntegerField())`?

Comment: But the `ouptut_field` is *not* an extra annotation, it is a parameter that is part of the `Func`.

Comment: Willem's comment works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely this is because Django can not inference the type of the field. You can give it a "hint" by specifing this through the `output_field` parameter:

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField

qs = Document.objects.annotate(
    content_len=Func(F('content'), function='CARDINALITY', output_field=IntegerField())
).exclude(content_len=0)
```